# Android: How to add pw/security to the time/date settings of the phone to keep the user from changing it

Tags: android, security, date, time, passwords

My app will have a 'clock in' in the listview. As a user will click that item it will grab the time/date from the phone itself and send that data out to the server. I prefer doing this over using server time since if they dont have a signal/reception they wont be able to clock in. I would like to add a password security to the time/date settings itself so the user wont be able to take advantage of changing the time when clocking in. How can I make that happen?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you'll have to write a custom ROM for this.

Comment: is that the only way? another other way to access to the root of the phone where i can modify the time/date settings security?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html Is all you get from being a Device Admin.  I don't see anything about restricting date/time changes.  That said, even if you could stop them from changing the clock, you can't stop them from "clocking in" an hour before they start "working", no?

Comment: I thought of a possible alternative - see the Answers section.

Comment: thats a good point. But The client prefers that the user cant change the time/date which is better than giving them access to change it. And as for the clocking in earlier thats the risk they are willing to take. Is there link thats compatible to 1.5 since the phone is i1 motorola and its not upgradable and the link you gave me is only for 2.2+

Comment: I believe the "Admin" feature was added in 2.2 so you're out of luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to just send message to server "user X wants to clock in". And server will use its local time for "clocking in". This way you will completely ignore device's time, and have more control over your infrastructure.

In general, if you want something to be as secure as possible, don't do this on the client side (unless you absolutely have to). And in this case user may gain root on his device and use some command line magic to fool you server with fake date/time. Its not that hard. And you just won't be able to predict all the smart workarounds of you "time protection".

Comment: I think the best solution is to use a server when you can, and provisionally take into account (but record as not absolutely trusted) one or more pieces of data from the client side when the server can't be reached. A solution which works in the majority of cases, and helps identify the minority of situations which the involved live humans should discuss should go pretty far.

Comment: if I decided to do the server time method. What can I do to clock in while in the zone with no reception? If no reception, can I 'clock in' and store the data in the phone with the time/date, and attempt to send that data every 10 min (as the phone is attempting to get the reception)

Comment: Look at `ConnectivityManager` and its broadcast intent `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. It will be sent each time connectivity appears or goes away. This way you won't need to poll manually for connectivity status. But be aware, that use can cheat while his device is offline.

Comment: Using ConnectivityManager, the way it works, would it save the time/date at the time of the 'clock in' in the phone while offline and as soon as reception is available it will send that data. Did I get that right?

Comment: `ConnectivityManager` will only notify you of connectivity changes, you'll need to manage the `time` part yourself. Scenario: user clocks in, you check connectivity. A: you have connectivity, send "clock in" request. B: you do not have connectivity, wait for `ConnectivityManager` to notify you about connectivity, send "clock in" request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, but you can cross-check the time.

When you "clock in" also open /proc/uptime as a text file and read the value there.  I believe it is in seconds.  When you clock out, re-read the value and use the difference as a cross-check.  If a server is also available, check the time from the server too (or report the clocking in immediately)

If the phone crashes or is powered off in between, the difference in uptime could be less than what you've recorded via the ordinary clock.  In that case, the difference in uptime might be less than the ordinary clock (likely it will be negative) so if your clock-in was done without access to network time your software may have to have a way to report that particular result as unverified, and track the number of unverifieds per user to flag for human review if it becomes excessive.

A user could conceivably compile and install a kernel that lies about uptime, but that person could probably get around most of the other things you would do, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a service to run every minute (or so) that checks the time.  If the time is not ~1 minute after the last check then it may have been changed.  You should confirm with the server at this point to make sure the discrepancy wasn't caused by rebooting the phone.

If you find that the time was changed, you can change it back or log this with your main application and flag the "user" for disciplinary actions.

Comment: Wont this keep waking the phone up from sleep, and so deplete the battery?  15 minutes might be more reasonable, 12 or 18 if you have one of those timekeeping systems that divides an hour into tenths.

Comment: The developer would have to test and tweak the setting to make it as useful as possible.  However, if the gap is too big, the user could potentially change the clock, "clock in" then turn the clock back to the correct time within the gap between 2 checks.

Comment: This sounds good but I dont think the client would like the app to be running in the background and drain the battery more than it suppose to do.

Comment: If you log each check, the user would have to change the clock multiple times, making sure to set it to just before each time the logging code should run.  Unless the user is writing a program to do this (and if they are, you have more to worry about) I think they may find it easier to actually show up for work.

Comment: Good point - the user is unlikely to be precise in his trickery.  The game is afoot!

Comment: The employees are mostly out the field doing jobs on construction. The company's old system was the older phone motorola i355 and they were able to add a security to keep the time/date settings from changing. Now the company wanted to update the phones which is now motorola i1 (latest android nextel) and continue that same method on android as their old ways.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like that won't be possible without a custom ROM.

Comment: Is there a ROM out there right now where i can take it and just modify the time/date settings and then install it on every employees phone but ROM will need to be as stock as possible as the phone would be when first bought it.

Comment: I have no clue if one exists.  You'll want to ask that in a new question and it may be better suited for android.stackexchange.com

Comment: android.stackexchange would probably reject it as development rather than usage question

Comment: I think he's now looking for an open source ROM that will run on the phone.. it's sort of in limbo between stackoverflow and android.stackexchange.com.  Perhaps a Motorola enthusiast site is the right place for that question.

Comment: Deploying a customized rom is going to greatly increase the complexity of the project and likely create support issues.  Combining all of the other ideas - {going direct to server when possible, periodic timestamps, cross check against /proc/uptime} should provide a workable solution that can be deployed as an SDK app onto unmodified devices.

Comment: Thanks I do agreed with Chris. I do believe it would be more complicated and alot of conflict between the app im creating and the customized ROM.